# How do I predict from a SageMaker endpoint using a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-sagemaker

So I'm trying to use the models that I have created using autopilot in SageMaker Studio but I keep getting different errors. Ultimately I want it to be simple; take a dataframe and predict an output using that dataframe (pandas obviously). Here's what I have so far followed by the errors that I am getting.

```
import sagemaker, boto3, os
bucket = sagemaker.Session().default_bucket()

model = sagemaker.predictor.Predictor('Predict-Low', sagemaker_session=sagemaker.Session())

df = pd.read_csv('s3://sagemaker-studio-xxx/Sagemaker Data Predict Low.csv')

y = df['Low']
del df['Low']

y_hat = model.predict(df)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParamValidationError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-18ff980cf441> in <module>
----> 1 y_hat = model.predict(df)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/predictor.py in predict(self, data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant, inference_id)
    134             data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant, inference_id
    135         )
--> 136         response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
    137         return self._handle_response(response)
    138 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    384                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    385             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 386             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    387 
    388         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    676         }
    677         request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(
--> 678             api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
    679 
    680         service_id = self._service_model.service_id.hyphenize()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _convert_to_request_dict(self, api_params, operation_model, context)
    724             api_params, operation_model, context)
    725         request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(
--> 726             api_params, operation_model)
    727         if not self._client_config.inject_host_prefix:
    728             request_dict.pop('host_prefix', None)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/validate.py in serialize_to_request(self, parameters, operation_model)
    317                                                     operation_model.input_shape)
    318             if report.has_errors():
--> 319                 raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
    320         return self._serializer.serialize_to_request(parameters,
    321                                                      operation_model)

ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body
```

To me it seems like it wants a string of bytes to do the prediction, so that's what I did. I converted the dataframe to a string of bytes and still got an error. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

By the way this is all being done in SageMaker Studio. Here is the data.

```
     Date         Company   High    Low  Open  Close  Volume  Adj Close  \
0    7/13/2020    LIFE  4.380  3.880  4.21   3.88   62400       3.88   
1    7/14/2020    LIFE  4.210  3.721  3.95   4.16   80800       4.16   
2    7/15/2020    LIFE  4.550  4.053  4.17   4.50  212500       4.50   
3    7/16/2020    LIFE  4.550  4.350  4.40   4.51   44600       4.51   
4    7/17/2020    LIFE  5.170  4.410  4.54   5.09  257700       5.09   
..         ...     ...    ...    ...   ...    ...     ...        ...   
255  7/16/2021    LIFE  4.590  4.440  4.46   4.50  156300       4.50   
256  7/19/2021    LIFE  4.490  4.220  4.36   4.22  211700       4.22   
257  7/20/2021    LIFE  4.546  4.230  4.23   4.47  212500       4.47   
258  7/21/2021    LIFE  4.800  4.369  4.45   4.48  487500       4.48   
259  7/22/2021    LIFE  4.510  4.260  4.44   4.45  235200       4.45   

          Sector                                          Specifics  \
0    Health Care  Biotechnology: Biological Products (No Diagnos...   
1    Health Care  Biotechnology: Biological Products (No Diagnos...   
2    Health Care  Biotechnology: Biological Products (No Diagnos...   
3    Health Care  Biotechnology: Biological Products (No Diagnos...   
4    Health Care  Biotechnology: Biological Products (No Diagnos...   
..           ...                                                ...   
255  Health Care  Biotechnology: Biological Products (No Diagnos...   
256  Health Care  Biotechnology: Biological Products (No Diagnos...   
257  Health Care  Biotechnology: Biological Products (No Diagnos...   
258  Health Care  Biotechnology: Biological Products (No Diagnos...   
259  Health Care  Biotechnology: Biological Products (No Diagnos...   

     Open Difference from Yesterday  Yesterday Open to Low  \
0                              0.00                  0.000   
1                             -0.26                  0.330   
2                              0.22                  0.229   
3                              0.23                  0.117   
4                              0.14                  0.050   
..                              ...                    ...   
255                            0.01                  0.080   
256                           -0.10                  0.020   
257                           -0.13                  0.140   
258                            0.22                  0.000   
259                           -0.01                  0.081   

     Yesterday Open to High  Yesterday Open to Adj Close  
0                     0.000                         0.00  
1                     0.170                        -0.33  
2                     0.260                         0.21  
3                     0.380                         0.33  
4                     0.150                         0.11  
..                      ...                          ...  
255                   0.100                         0.00  
256                   0.130                         0.04  
257                   0.130                        -0.14  
258                   0.316                         0.24  
259                   0.350                         0.03
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that you need to specify a serializer for your model in order to make predictions. Adding this code before `model.predict(...)` will do it.

```
from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer
model.serializer = CSVSerializer()
```